# Как вводить и посимвольно проверять строку?

Tags: python, tkinter, валидация

проблема в следующем: пользователь вводит строку в которой есть символы обязательны должны быть в строке, а есть которые могут быть любыми,например, строка:name.create_text(x,y, text='Текст'), в этой строке изменяемыми могут быть 1)name, могут быть разные названия 2) Текст, вместо него может быть любой текст 3) и после ' может быть anchor= 'здесь выбирает пользователь'. Я пытался сделать с валидацией, но не понял как сделать так чтобы пользовать мог сам вводить свои данные, а не строго по строке.
Пример неправильного кода:

```
from tkinter import *


def char_validate(d, P):
    pattern = "c.create_text(x,y, text='Текст')"
    if d == '1':
        if P == pattern:
            print('Вы правильно ввели всю строку')
        elif pattern.startswith(P):
            print('Вводите дальше')
        else:
            print('Введен неверный символ!')
    return True


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')

field_check = (root.register(char_validate),"%d", "%P")
c = Canvas(root)
x= 100
y= 100
c.create_text(x,y, text='Текст')
c.pack()

field = Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=field_check)
field.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: на самом деле, вопрос про то, как составить регулярное выражение, соответствующее шаблону ввода. Вы пробовали что-то сделать?

Comment: @splash58 я когда искал видел конструкцию по типу r'[0-9]" и пытался как-то соединить с исходной строкой, но безуспешно

Comment: ну, с регуляркой я вам помогу, но так вы не сможете посимвольно проверять (вернее сможете, но с очень большим гемором), а только все выражение сразу - https://regex101.com/r/yq3G42/1

Comment: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-validation/

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, но не совсем понял как с этой строкой работать, мне получается нужно её ввести вместо той, что стоит в pattern?

Comment: но проверять можно будет только, когда она введена полностью. а как проверять - прочитайте про регулярки в питон